# Use a checkmark as a bullet

Tags: indentation, bullets

I am using LaTeX to write up a marking scheme for a school test.

I would like to use the checkmark character from the `pifont` (`\ding{51}`) as a bullet point. However, I am trying to copy the formatting, and due to the requirements of the formatting I don't wish to use it in the `enumerate` environment.

I would like to replicate a similar environment as I have set up in Microsoft Word, where the checkmark/bullet point is set at 0 cm, and the text need to it is set with an indent of 0.6 cm (see the picture below).

[image]

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly is it you want to do in latex?

Comment: Could you post a compilable code of what you've tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything @Bernard.

Comment: @daleif I would like to replicate what is shown in the screen shot from Microsoft Word. I would like to have the checkmark, and then tab to enter in text that relates to that mark.

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding,enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[label=\CheckmarkBold]
\item Correct answer.
\item Also correct
\item[\XSolidBrush] Not correct answer.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The spacing and gaps can be tuned with the `enumitem` options (text margin shown for clarity):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding,enumitem}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=10pt,labelsep=0pt,itemsep=-3pt,label=\CheckmarkBold]
\item Correct answer.
\item Also correct
\item[\XSolidBrush] Not correct answer which goes on long enough so that you
  can see the item margin gives you what you want.
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can get an assortment of checks from `symbols-a4.pdf`

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Steven, however I don't wish to use the `itemise` environment as it indents the checkmarks and places white space before and after there items. Can I remove these?

Comment: @C.deHaer Outside of an `itemize`, you can merely type `\CheckmarkBold{} My comment` to get the isolated check + text.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, but when the text carries onto the next line I would like it to line up with the start of the text, and not the checkmark.

Comment: @C.deHaer That's what `itemize` does for you.  You can use other features of `enumitem` to change the indents, margins, etc, to get the desired appearance.

Comment: @C.deHaer Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend Stephen's approach, but if you really wanted an alternative, some parboxes may work, too:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding}              % Symbols
\usepackage{calc}                % Arithmetic with lengths
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % only to show the margins
\usepackage{mwe}                 % For this example MWE
\newcommand{\checked}[2][0.6cm]{%
  \noindent\parbox[t]{#1}{\raggedright\CheckmarkBold}\parbox[t]{\linewidth-#1}{#2}%
}
\begin{document}
\checked{Correct answer.}
\checked{Long correct answer. \blindtext[1]}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of compiled document]

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on not using itemize or enumerate, I suggest using tabular or tabularx:

```
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1em}X}
\mycheckmark{} & my text\\
\mycheckmark{} & more text
\end{tabularx}
```

You might want to fiddle with the width of the first column, depending on what you pick for your check mark.